# How to write all possible combinations

Tags: c#, math, combinatorics

For a better understanding, I'll give you a simple example:
We have 10 lamps. We can light one or two. It is necessary to write down all the ways to light the two lamps. This example is simple. And we can just list all the options like this:

```
List<string> lstAllOptions = new List<string> ( );

            for ( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
            {
                lstAllOptions.Add ( i.ToString ( ) );
            }

            for ( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
            {
                for ( int j = 1; j <= 10; j++ )
                {
                    if ( i != j && j>i )
                    {
                        lstAllOptions.Add ( i.ToString ( ) + " and " + j.ToString ( ) );
                    }
                }
            }
```

But what if the user sets the number of lamps? We can have 43 lamps and the ability to turn on 19 of them. Or as much as you like. I can increase the number of For, but it is very difficult. How to solve this problem easier and make a universal method for any number of lamps?

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion? --- Code review note: instead of doing the `i != j && j>i` test in the inner loop you can make it start above `i` with `for ( int j = i + 1; j <= 10; j++ )`.

Comment: `43C19` is more than 800 billion, so that would take a while to compute...

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote [an excellent series of blog posts](https://ericlippert.com/tag/permutations/) on producing combinations and permutations back in 2014.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can compute such a combination:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> AllCombinations(int n, int k) =>
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << n)
    let r = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(j => ((i & 1 << j) == 0 ? 1 : 0))
    where r.Count(s => s == 1) <= k
    select r;
```

However, with `n == 43` it blows pat what an integer can hold.

It does work for lower values:

```
Console.WriteLine(AllCombinations(24, 19).Count());
```

Gives:

```
16764265
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. nCk is n!/(k!*(n-k)!) so 24C19 is 24!/(19!*5!) which is 42,504 - not 16,764,265

Comment: @MatthewWatson - The OP asked for the `nCj` where `j is in 0 .. k`. It's not just `nCk`.